# How to run MRUnit?

Tags: hadoop, junit, mapreduce

I've written an MRUnit to test my mapper. However, I don't know how to run it in Eclipse as it reads some data from distributedCache. When I run it as a normal class in Eclipse it give me a bunch of errors. These are the error messages I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.<clinit>(TestDriver.java:38)
    at MapperCombinerReducerTester.setUp(MapperCombinerReducerTester.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error relates to a dependency library (commons-logging) not being on the classpath. Are you using Maven (combined with m2e) to manage your project dependencies, or are you using a straight Java Project in Eclipse?

Testing mappers / reducers which depend on the distributed cache is also tricky with MRUnit as 0.9.0 doesn't have support for emulating the distributed cache (coming in 1.0.0 if you look at the [JIRA tickets](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20=%20MRUNIT%20AND%20text%20~%20%22Distributed%20Cache%22)). One way i've done this before is to assume the use of symlinking your local cached files, and in the setup of my unit test copying the file to the local directory (messy but it works).